# Error CS046: the type or namespace namespace name 'List<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#

This is the function of my code. I am getting following error after executing this function:

> Error CS0246: the type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public class ListsExercise {

    public static List<int> Solution() {
        // TODO: write your solution here
        //create a new list 
        List<int> myList = new List<int>();
        //go thorugh every number beyweem 100 and 170
        for (int i = 100; i <= 170; i++) {
            //check if its an even number
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                //add it to the list
                myList.Add(i);
            }
        }
        //return the list
        return myList;
    }
}
```

I am new in C#, Anyone please help me to resolve this issue.   Thanks in advance

Comment: add `using System.Collections.Generic;` to the top of the file

Comment: Add `using System.Collections.Generic;` to the top of your code file.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio not only reports an error, but also presents you a solution in a [Smart Tag (light bulb)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quick-actions?view=vs-2022#to-see-a-light-bulb-or-screwdriver) that offers you to add the missing `using` directive (just click on it to add the using directive):

[image]